# ASP.net MVC HTTP Error 403.14 after changing out-of-the-box route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC application with default routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

after implementing the whole project i need to change routing to

```
routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "Default",
                     url: "app/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

**it gives me HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: So what is you problem?

Comment: You answered your question!

Comment: no its not working like that it gives me HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: If the original worked prior to the change, check to make sure you do not have a directory named "app" on your IIS website.

Comment: Can you list framework and webserver versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [.NET Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) that route is correct. From the documentation:

> blog/{action}/{entry}
>   /blog/show/123

I would make sure that you have checked that:

1) The URL your localhost is calling matches your new routing.

2) You have defined a GET method in your controller.

3) Your "app" is case sensitive.

4) You place your new routing (if there are multiple) first.

I would ask in comments, but I don't have the reputation yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to configure a default document in IIS. Or you need to request a particular URL to trigger your routing.

Another possibility is that a physical folder exists which path is the same as the route you're trying to hit.

From [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942062) verbatim re:
**Add a default document**

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type
   inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
2. In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click
   the website that you want to modify.
3. In the Features view, double-click Default Document.
4. In the Actions pane, click Enable.
5. In the File Name box, type the name of the default document, and
   then click OK.